# React Native - centering flexWrap content

Tags: javascript, reactjs, layout, react-native, flexbox

I have a `View` which needs to render items in a list. The items need to be rendered in a row and then wrap around. I am able to achieve this behavior by using `flexDirection` and `flexWrap` as below. The problem is that the wrapped rows all appear left justified thus leaving an undetermined space towards the right. This makes some sense but I'm wondering if there is a way to center the content in each row that `flexWrap` creates?

```
<View style={{alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center'}}>
  <View style={{alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center', flexDirection: 'row', flexWrap: 'wrap'}}>
    <Item value={1} />
    <Item value={2} />
    <Item value={3} />
  </View>
</View>
```

Comment: you can play around with flex here and find the right combination of values to achieve what you want http://the-echoplex.net/flexyboxes/

Comment: Have you tried adding `justifyContent: 'center'`? That would be the property to use for horizontal alignment in `flexDirection: 'row'`.

Comment: Thanks for sharing the link on flexyboxes. A very handy tool. I was able to get it working on flexyboxes by setting `justifyContent` and `alignContent` to `center` but still have no luck in my project. FWIW, React Native doesn't support `alignContent` and adding `justifyContent` to my `View` seems to have no effect.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The external `alignItems` somehow gets in the way. I'm not sure about the inner workings and why this works but the code below now works as expected.

```
<View style={{justifyContent: 'center'}}>
  <View style={{alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center', flexDirection: 'row', flexWrap: 'wrap'}}>
    <Item value={1} />
    <Item value={2} />
    <Item value={3} />
  </View>
</View>
```